# REST C# Get List Items

Tags: c#, xml, rest

I am completely new to REST API.
I would like to retrieve ListItems in xml format from an external site in C#.
I have got the username and password for the site (which uses Mixed authentication by the way).

```
HttpWebRequest endpointRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("https://<site>/_api/web/lists");
endpointRequest.Method = "GET";
endpointRequest.Accept = "application/atom+xml";
//endpointRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);



endpointRequest.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes("<domain>\\<username>:<password>"));

HttpWebResponse endpointResponse = (HttpWebResponse)endpointRequest.GetResponse();
```

I am using this piece of code that I found on MSDN.
Would anybody please be kind enough to tell me how do I get an access token?
Why am I getting 403 Forbidden error?

Comment: The access token comes from the web site you are making the request of.  Each site has different methods of authenticating users via their API.  Here is the method for the Microsoft translator API: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh454950.aspx.  The API calls for requesting a token are often based on oAuth, so you might want to do some research here.  It can be somewhat of a deep hole the first time you get into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can better use the NetworkCredential class:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);   
NetworkCredential credentials = new NetworkCredential("testuser", "testpass");  
request.Credentials = credentials;
```

No need to send the Authorization header

Answer (score 0):

When I have to use REST API I use [Tiny.RestClient](https://github.com/jgiacomini/Tiny.RestClient) [1](https://github.com/jgiacomini/Tiny.RestClient)

In your case you have to write the call like that :

```
var client = new TinyRestClient(new HttpClient(), "https://<site>/_api/");

client.GetRequest("web/lists")
```

Hopes that help.
    WithBasicAuthentication("username", "password").
    ExecuteAsync();